# Downloading a file from sharepoint using java program

Tags: java, sharepoint, cookies, redirect

I'm trying to download an excel workbook from a sharepoint site using java program. However I'm getting the error : ***Server redirected too many  times (20)***.  I searched the forums and it appears to be an issue with cookies. After searching the forums, I added the first line of code  to set default cookie handler, but the error still exists.

The java program is part of an osgi bundle.  Strangely the program works when I run from my local PC running an instance of servicemix.  But when I deploy this on the servicemix running on a remote server (linux machine), it gives this error.

I wanted to do this without having to use any third party libraries like apache-http etc.

Any suggestions what could be going wrong here?

```
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));


    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {          
            return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, 
                    PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        }
    });

    URL website = new URL(dataLocation);
    // data location points to the sharepoint file
    // its something like 
    // http://<company.sharepointsite.com>/project/sites/SampleProject/ProjectDocuments/Sample.xlsx


    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? In both cases, consider using the client-side object model (CSOM), exposed through web services. In the older versions of SharePoint (2007,2010), the web service is ASMX while the newer versions are RESTful. This way you use the supported SharePoint object model correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended up using Apache HTTP libraries which solved the problem.  although this is an old post, I'm updating this as it might help others who are facing similar issue. 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents